# Trying to append a div to the document using vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append a an element to the document with vanilla JavaScript but it's giving me this error: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('') is not a valid name."

This is all my js code:

```js
function newProject(root,img) {
    const project = document.createElement("<div class='element'><a href='" + root +"'><img src='"+ img +"'></a></div>");
    const element = document.querySelector(".projects");
    element.appendChild(project);
}

newProject('../projects/periodic-table/tabla-periodica.html', '../img/tabla-valencias.png');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.createElement` will only create a single *empty* element, e.g., `<div></div>`, and only takes the tag name (`div`) as a parameter. So you should construct your elements manually like this:

```
const project = document.createElement('div');
project.className = 'element';

const projectLink = document.createElement('a');
projectLink.href = root;
project.appendChild(projectLink);

const image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = img;
project.appendChild(image);
```

---

<sub>You can also use `.innerHTML` to insert HTML content into a node directly, but for dynamic content (i.e., generated by variables, such as in your case). I'd recommend against this as this doesn't escape the contents of the variables and leaves you vurnerable to XSS attacks on your code.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As Frxstrem said, `createElement` creates a single empty element. You give it a **tag name**, not an HTML string.

You can use an HTML string to append to an existing element in the DOM (or prepend to it, or insert before or after it) via [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Here's how that would look in your example:

```js
function newProject(root, img) {
    const element = document.querySelector(".projects");
    element.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        "<div class='element'><a href='" + root +"'><img src='"+ img +"'></a></div>"
    );
}

/* Using your paths:
newProject('../projects/periodic-table/tabla-periodica.html', '../img/tabla-valencias.png');
*/
// For the purposes of this demo:
newProject("http://example.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=This is an example");
```

```html
<div class="projects"></div>
```

*(I've swapped out your image path for something that will show up in the snippet.)*

You can also assign to [the `innerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to completely replace an element's contents. (But don't use `+=` to repeatedly add to it, it makes the browser do a lot of unnecessary work.)